# Java - Dynamically creating concrete type of an Interface?

Tags: java, oop, interface, polymorphism, pojo

In my java class below I create a product and calculate the shipping as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // create product 
    Product product = new Product();
    
    // calculate shipping
    ShippingCalculator usaShippingCalculator = new USAShippingCalculator();
    usaShippingCalculator.calculatePrice(product);

   // todo - how to replace above with dynamic logic around what calculator to use?
    
    }
```

Note that I have 2 different shipping calculators:

```
USAShippingCalculator
RestofWorldShippingCalculator
```

Both implement the `ShippingCalculator` interface, shown below:

```
public interface ShippingCalculator {

    void calculatePrice(Product product);
}
```

Note that I have hardcoded above to use the `USAShippingCalculator`, however what I want to do is dynamically use the calculator that corresponds to the products country of origin - this will be a field in the Product object : `String countryOfOrigin.`

How can I do so?

Comment: Define a variable of type `ShippingCalculator`, have an `if` statement based on the `countryOfOrigin`. In the if-block create a `USAShippingCalculator` and assign it to the variable, in the else-block create a `RestOfWorldShippingCalculator` and assign it to the variable. There's probably nothing in there that you haven't done dozens of times before, it's just a combination that you've not seen before, but you know the individual steps. Bonus points: extract the `if` into a a method like `ShippingCalculator getShippingCalculator(String countryOfOrigin)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unlikely to need these calculators anywhere else in your code, you could use anonymous inner classes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // create product 
    Product product = new Product();
    
    ShippingCalculator shippingCalculator;
    // calculate shipping
    if(product.countryOfOrigin.equals("USA"))
       shippingCalculator = new ShippingCalculator(){
         void calculatePrice(Product product){
             //do usa calculation
         }
       }
    else
       shippingCalculator = new ShippingCalculator() {
         void calculatePrice(Product product){
             //do non-usa calculation
         }
       }
    
    shippingCalculator.calculatePrice(product);

}
```